# Traveling abroad for about four years and working as a freelance writer. Who do I pay taxes to?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, norway

I've currently been traveling around the world, just recently finished studying in Thailand and am going to be employed in Norway working in the service industry. I've worked there before, filed a resident permit, and have payed taxes in Norway.

However, I have also landed a freelance writing position from a media company based in Toronto, CA. I work from my computer, constantly traveling and through multiple countries. Being that my last official place of residence was a temporary residence visa stay in Norway, do I have to pay taxes from my freelance writing position as well? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: And you're citizen of...?

Comment: I'm an American citizen

Comment: when I traveled as a contractor about 10 years ago, I just didn't pay taxes... but my original country of citizenship didn't really have the will to enforce its tax laws on expats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a US citizen, you pay your taxes to the US Federal government on *worldwide* income, regardless of your residency. Check your State laws (the State where you're considered resident, vote for example) about whether you also need to pay state taxes.

Also, depending on the country in which you earn the income, you might have to pay taxes there. You'll have to specifically check the laws of each country to know how much you have to pay, and how to report it. Generally, countries tax income sourced on their soil, but some (like US) may also tax income sourced elsewhere if they deem you to be their tax resident.

Since you're a US citizen, tax treaties between the US and the relevant countries are also affecting you. There's a tax treaty between the US and Canada, for example.

You'll have to check if your tax residency in Norway has been terminated. Generally one would assume that when your period of stay on a temporary visa is over - you're no longer tax resident. But that's logic, laws may be different.